# how to change text direction to the right slide of switch in android?

Tags: android, text, switch-statement

In default mode , text of a `Switch` sit on the left side of **ON/OFF** states. I want to change direction of this text to the right slide. How can i do this?

I already try this `xml` code but not working:

```
<Switch
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/switch1"
android:layout_gravity:"right"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_text_padding_right"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set text position to the right of a Switch (like CheckBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983522/how-to-set-text-position-to-the-right-of-a-switch-like-checkbox)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK thats not doable, you can try the following

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch_gprs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/switch_gprs"
            android:text="sometext"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My Switch"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`android:layoutDirection="rtl"`

Comment: This question is duplicated and already has an answer, the same as yours but with an explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983522/how-to-set-text-position-to-the-right-of-a-switch-like-checkbox

Comment: Hmm I had not seen that answer, thank you very much.