# Change switch direction of the switch

Tags: android, button, view, android-widget

How can I change the direction of the switch modes in Android?
Mode turned on will be on the left and mode turned off will be on the right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change text direction to the right slide of switch in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702713/how-to-change-text-direction-to-the-right-slide-of-switch-in-android)

Comment: you can write a custom switch and use it refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33231991/6414107